# How can I have 4 divs inside a div that are all equal in size and are not joined together?

Tags: html, css

Here is an example of what I'm describing:

[image: Valid XHTML]

Answer (score 3):

Simple way to achieve the thing you want : use of `float:left` do work for you

```
<div style="width:100%">
 <div style="width:100%">
   <div style="width:45%; float:left">  
      div1
   </div>
   <div style="width:45%; ">  
      div2
   </div>
 </div>
 <div style="width:100%">
   <div style="width:45%; float:left">  
      div3
   </div>
   <div style="width:45%; ">  
      div4
   </div>
 </div>      
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `float` and `margin` to solve your problem as [rahul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245428/how-can-i-have-4-divs-inside-a-div-that-are-all-equal-in-size-and-are-not-joined/3245444#3245444) already suggested. To have 2 floats next to each other use `width`.

CSS:

```
.outer {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.inner {
  margin: 10px;
  float:left;
  width:45%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">div</div>
  <div class="inner">div</div>
  <div class="inner">div</div>
  <div class="inner">div</div>
</div>
```

I used 45% for the width of the floats, to make sure that they fit. 50% is not working due to the `margin`. The 45% could be increased slight more I guess, but that depends on the margin of the inner divs.

Comment: the inner div does not need a class if you want to save some characters. you can use the css selector as this: `.outer div` or `.outer > div` if you only want to select the first childs

Comment: True, but using more complex CSS selectors (such as child and descendant selectors) seems to slow down browsers. So in this situation it is easily prevented.

Answer (score 1):

This could be your HTML:

```
<div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

And this could be your CSS:

```
div {
    float: left; /* so the surrounding div takes only the size of its content */
    padding: 20px 0 0 20px; /* to get the same spacing everywhere */
    overflow: hidden; /* this is not needed but i like to use it because clients never do what they shoul :P */
    border: 4px solid black;
}

div > div {
    float: left; /* places the divs next to each other */
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 20px 20px 0; /* makes the space between the divs */
    border: 4px solid black;
}

div > div:nth-child(3n) {
    clear: both; /* you want the 3rd div to start a new line */
}
```

and this would be the result:
http://jsfiddle.net/NgjaY/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you want the divs to be side by side then you can use the `float` property. If you want seperation between the divs then you can use `margin` property.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#main   {
    width:130px;
    padding:10px 0px 0px 0px;
    height:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:#171817;
}

.div1   {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    margin:0px 0px 10px 10px;
    background-color:white; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <div class="div1"></div>
    <div class="div1"></div>
    <div class="div1"></div>
    <div class="div1"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if your value is 0 you don't need to specify the unit. 0 is always 0 :P

Comment: Adding the units is much clearer and a good thing to do IMHO. And 0 is not always 0, for example 0 degrees Celsius is not the same as 0 degrees Fahrenheit or Kelvin

Comment: @vergel: this is a bad argumentation i think. you never gonna use farenheit in a CSS style sheet. When you use a size 0 is always 0. I would always avoid to write useless stuff in any kind of code. It only would make sense if it would clarify something. But as you know 0px == 0pt == 0%. 

Using them makes your CSS heavier, longer to write and it hurts my eyes